# Shell script to Sudo in Remote Machine and execute commands

Tags: linux, sudo

```
#!/bin/csh
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no xyz123@remotemachine.com
sudo -su rootuser
ksh
. /mydir/setup_env.ksh
ls -ltr
```

Above is the list of task i  need to do.

1. Login into remote machine without password prompt
2. Run Sudo to get access to Root
3. Change shell to ksh
4. execute a script (setup_env.ksh)
5. List files using ls -ltr

When i execute this script from , lets say localunixmachine.com...

1. It ask me for password
2. once i enter password , it will transfer to remote machine but wont execute remaining commands
3. If i exit from remote session, it will execute remaining command.

Can you please Guide me whats the best way to accomplish what i am trying here.

Answer (score 0):

first you can copy your ssh public key which you can generate `ssh-keygen` to authorized_keys to the remote server root/.ssh/authorized_keys
and then the script will be

```
ssh root@remotemachine.com "/bin/ksh mydir/setup_env.ksh"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for executing multiple commands remotely:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no xyz123@remotemachine.com <<EOF
sudo -su rootuser
ksh
. /mydir/setup_env.ksh
ls -ltr
EOF
```

As for login to the server without password, you need to setup ssh authentication with keys.